# Customizing Select in mantine to prevent dropdown options from being cut off

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, mantine

Currently my select tab is cut off at the top, based on the size of the component it is contained within. This means the first option in my select dropdown doesn't show clearly as the top is cut off.

Here is an example

[image]

I am using mantine to implement this form. I have tried toggling the dropdownPosition property to top and editing the zIndex, ensuring the zIndex of the select options is higher than that of the form, along with adding an overflow property. None of this has worked.

The desired outcome is to have the options overflowing past the container so they are not cut off. The dropdown options should overflow to the top and not the bottom

Here is my code for the select dropdown:

```
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          zIndex: 10,
          maxHeight: '200px', // Set the maximum height as per your requirement
          overflowY: 'auto', // Enable vertical scrolling
        }}
      >
        <Select
          ...
          styles={{
            label: { fontWeight: MODALS.LABEL_FONT_WEIGHT },
          dropdownPosition='top'
          ...
        />
      </div>
    )
```

Here is the code for the form itself:

...

this component is imported and reused here:

```
<Form
  ...
/>
```

)

Answer (score 2):

It might be too late for you but i will post the solution because i struggled like you to fix this kind of behaviour:

```
popoverProps:{withinPortal: true}
```

I usually set this default property project wise in my Theme file

```
    DateInput: {
        defaultProps: {
            popoverProps:{withinPortal: true}
        }
    },
```

Comment: I had the same problem and passing the "withinPortal" prop to "true" on my Select worked like a charm, I think this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The worth noting in your inline style, the curious part is maxHeight of div which contain the select component. From your attached image, You will notice that the drop list is cut off at 200px from bottom of select tag not first item.
In my opinion, The display property of the select list of HTML's select tag is originally absolute so that it doesn't distribute the other nested elements. So you don't need to consider the height. Please try without maxHeight value.

Comment: Tried this, but the option is still truncated

Comment: Please share your individual part of code in CodePen so that i can fix there. I am not able to provide you more detailed solution without your code.